# SSL certificate for meta.gis.stackexchange.com expired/domain mismatch

Tags: support

The SSL certificate for meta.gis.stackexchange.com expired on 2020-09-06. Also, it is not valid for that domain...

The domain is apparently only a redirect to gis.meta.stackexchange.com, which has a correct certificate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has never been valid for that domain, because it's not possible to request a wildcard domain for `meta.*.stackexchange.com`. This is the main reason they switched to https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com during the great HTTP → HTTPS migration: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232).

There should be no links in the system pointing to https://meta.gis.stackexchange.com, as that domain *never* was accessible via HTTPS. Its HTTP equivalent, http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com, properly redirects to this Meta site (in HTTPS). If you do see a link to https://meta.gis.stackexchange.com or its subpages, it must be because someone made an error.

Answer (score 2):

The certificate is valid for the ***.stackexchange.com** domain

[image]

If you have further information or want to contact an employee of stack exchange please go to https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact.

As a moderators are volunteers not employees.

Comment: Or raise such a problem on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)